# How can i add items to java text file through GUI combo box(netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox, text-files

I have already defined the items in the combo box inside gui. What happens is that im trying to add an entry to the program text file and it says: incompatible types int cannot be converted to string.
I am having problems with `setLocation` and `setSkills`.

```
private void buttonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                          

   Resort p = new Resort();
   p.setName(nameTextField.getText().replaceAll("[^a-z.]", ""));
   p.setLocation(comboResortLocation.getSelectedIndex());
   p.setSkillsByIndex(comboResortSkill.getSelectedIndex());
   txtfile.addResort(p);

   AddedConfirm confirmed = new AddedConfirm();
   confirmed.setVisible(true);
   this.setVisible(false);
}
```

And the part of the code from the other file.

```
public void setSkillsByIndex (String skills)
{
    this.skills = skills;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed already. 
I just had to change them to Strings and use getSelectedItem instead:

```
   p.setLocationByIndex((String) comboResortLocation.getSelectedItem());

   p.setSkillsByIndex((String) comboResortSkill.getSelectedItem());
```

and the other file:

public void setLocationByIndex (String location) 
        {
            this.location = location;

```
    }
```

public void setSkillsByIndex (String skills) {
            this.skills = skills;

```
    }
```